# Accessing Kubernetes api via Bearer Token Authorization

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to access a kubernetes cluster using the rest api. I followed the instructions of [this](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/access-cluster/) but i wanted to get the pods of the cluster.

```sh
APISERVER=$(kubectl config view --minify -o jsonpath='{.clusters[0].cluster.server}')
SECRET_NAME=$(kubectl get serviceaccount default -o jsonpath='{.secrets[0].name}')
TOKEN=$(kubectl get secret $SECRET_NAME -o jsonpath='{.data.token}' | base64 --decode)

curl $APISERVER/api/v1/pods --header "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" --insecure
```

the result is:

```
{
  "kind": "Status",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {

  },
  "status": "Failure",
  "message": "pods is forbidden: User \"system:serviceaccount:default:default\" cannot list resource \"pods\" in API group \"\" at the cluster scope",
  "reason": "Forbidden",
  "details": {
    "kind": "pods"
  },
  "code": 403
```

I tried the same `(curl localhost:8001/api/v1/pods)` by running the command:

```
kubectl proxy --address='0.0.0.0' --disable-filter=true
```

at the master node of the cluster and now it works as desired.

How can I make the Athorization Bearer work in the same manner?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `default` service account to get pods. `default` serviceaccount don't have that permission. You can check an action is allowed or not by running

```
$ kubectl auth can-i get pods --as system:serviceaccount:default:default
no
```

> "message": "pods is forbidden: User \"system:serviceaccount:default:default\" cannot list resource \"pods\" in API group \"\" at the cluster scope",

as can be seen above the default service account cannot list pods

but when given proper role and role binding like below

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  name: demo-role
  namespace: default
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - pods
  verbs:
  - get
  - list

---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: demo-binding
  namespace: default
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: Role
  name: demo-role
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: default
  namespace: default
```

Now if you check

```
$ kubectl auth can-i get pods --as system:serviceaccount:default:default
yes
```

If you want to list pods of default namespace using api then run

```
$ APISERVER=$(kubectl config view --minify -o jsonpath='{.clusters[0].cluster.server}')
$ SECRET_NAME=$(kubectl get serviceaccount default -o jsonpath='{.secrets[0].name}')
$ TOKEN=$(kubectl get secret $SECRET_NAME -o jsonpath='{.data.token}' | base64 --decode)

$ curl $APISERVER/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods --header "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" --insecure
{
  "kind": "PodList",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {
    "selfLink": "/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods",
    "resourceVersion": "1589"
  },
  "items": []
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to be able to get the pods for all the namespaces then you have to define a cluster-role and a cluster-role-binding, instead of a role/role-binding pair

```yaml
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: get-pods
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["pods"]
  verbs: ["get"]

---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: get-pods-binding
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: default
  namespace: default
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: get-pods
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

You may save this to a file named for example `get_pods_role.yaml` and execute `kubectl create -f get_pods_role.yaml`.
Then you will be able to get the desired output by this:

```sh
APISERVER=$(kubectl config view --minify -o jsonpath='{.clusters[0].cluster.server}')
SECRET_NAME=$(kubectl get serviceaccount default -o jsonpath='{.secrets[0].name}')
TOKEN=$(kubectl get secret $SECRET_NAME -o jsonpath='{.data.token}' | base64 --decode)

curl $APISERVER/api/v1/pods --header "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" --insecure
```

Answer (score 0):

If you’re using a Kubernetes cluster with RBAC enabled, the service account may not be authorized to access the API server. The simplest way to allow you to query the API server is to work around RBAC by running the following command:

```
kubectl create clusterrolebinding permissive-binding --clusterrole=cluster-admin --group=system:serviceaccounts
```

This gives all service accounts (we could also say all pods) cluster-admin privileges, allowing them to do whatever they want.
PLEASE NOTE:
**Obviously, doing this is dangerous and should never be done on production clusters.** For test purposes, it’s fine.

Comment: dangerous is an understatement